# call function marked with EXPORT_SYMBOL

Tags: c, linux, module, driver

I'm trying to execute a function of the linux module that I make. But I don't get success.

This is the [project](https://github.com/GuilhermeGiacomoSimoes/fp_printk)
I created a little function to convert an `int` to a `str float`:

```
void fp_printk(int number, int decimal_places, char* destination)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "um test no inicio");
    static char buffer[32] = { 0 };
    int buf_index = 30;
    int count_decimal_place = 0;
    int point_include = 0;

    for (; number && buf_index; --buf_index, number /= 10) {
        count_decimal_place++;
        if (!point_include && count_decimal_place > decimal_places) {
            buffer[buf_index] = '.';
            buf_index--;
            point_include = 1;
        }

        buffer[buf_index] = "0123456789"[number % 10];
    }

    strcpy(destination, &buffer[buf_index + 1]);
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(fp_printk);
```

And after converted, copy the str to destination parameter. 
and in my test module, I call:

```
    printk(KERN_INFO, "before exec\n");
    char *r = kmalloc(sizeof("12.34"), GFP_KERNEL);
    extern __visible void fp_printk(number, decimal_places, r);
    printk(KERN_INFO, "%s: %s\n", "test_fp_printk", r);
    printk(KERN_INFO, "after exec\n");
```

but when I run `sudo dmesg` for view printks, I only view:

```
[1210228.128703] test_fp_printk: before exec
[1210228.128712] test_fp_printk: after exec
```

it doesn't print the str `r`

if I call of fp_printk() in the module_init, it works.

```
static int __init fp_printk_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s: initial execute module", OURMODNAME);
    char *dest = kmalloc(sizeof("12.34"), GFP_KERNEL);
    fp_printk(1243, 2, dest); 
    printk(KERN_INFO, "%s", dest);
    return 0;
}
```

This work normally

I only need that `*destination` is filled with float str.